# What does $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_A f_k dm$ really mean?

Tags: integration, limits

What does $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_A f_k dm$ really mean?

That one first computes the integral, then takes the limit?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Yes. For each $k=1,2,3,\ldots$, there is a function $f_k$. Each function is integrated, giving a sequence $\int f_1, \int f_2\, \ldots$ and we take the limit of that sequence.